# Remove optional from array of characters - Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, database, option-type

How to remove optional and convert to natural characters array with using Swift 3 ??

this my code :

```
for data in listdata { // listdata is (Database) has a variable (ans)

    let tar = data.ans.characters.map({$0})

   lblLabel.text = String(describing: tar)

}

print(lblLabel.text)
```

> My output :
>   `Optional("[\"A\", \"B\", \"C\", \"D\"]")`

And I want to convert my output and adding text in the `lblLalbel` without optional and array like this :

> `A B C D`

How can I do that ??

Comment: `print(lblLabel.text!)`

Comment: it's work with print but in `targetLabel.text = String(describing: tar)` get me optional text in simulator, How can I do like print in text of label ?? @luk2302

Comment: What is the type of `tar`? And don't use `String(describing:)` to initialise a String, since it just uses the variable's `.description` property.

Comment: @DávidPásztor, not quite. Say, you need name of your class `YourViewController`, if you use `self.description()` you will get `ProjectTargetName.YourViewController`. But if you use `String(describing:self)` you will get `YourViewController`.

Comment: Now in my `lblLabel`adding text: `["A", "B", "C", "D"]` how can I remove array in the text of label ?? @AlekseyPotapov

Comment: see the @vacawama answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Optional" is coming from the fact that the `text` property of a label is of type `String?`.  You need to safely unwrap that when printing; using the *nil coalescing operator* `??` works nicely.

To get just the array items separated by a space, use `map { String($0) }` to convert the characters to `[String]` and then use `joined(separator: " ")` to join the elements together to form the final `String`:

```
for data in listdata { // listdata is (Database) has a variable (ans)

    let tar = data.ans.characters.map { String($0) }
    // Swift 4:  let tar = data.ans.map(String.init)

    lblLabel.text = tar.joined(separator: " ")

}

print(lblLabel.text ?? "")  // "A B C D"
```

Comment: When I'm writing `String.init` get me error : (Ambiguous use of 'init'), and when writing `String.init()` get me error : (No 'String.Type.init' candidates prouduce the expected contextual result type '(Character) throws -> _') @vacawama

Comment: Hmmm. String.init works for me. Try map { String($0) }.

Comment: Thanks, now it's working but I have 4 label and I want to add each label just one character how can I do that ?? @vacawama

Comment: @AmeenMK stop creating new questions / requirements on the fly. You should have started with that question. Because that changes the entire array and label handling.

Comment: Ok sorry @luk2302